# Is it possible to run selenium script from web browser?

Tags: java, python, selenium

I have a scrip (using Python) that submits to a form on www.example.com/form/info.php

currently my script will:
- open Firefox
- enter name, age, address
- press submit

what I want to do is have a web form (with name, age, address) on LAMP and when the user press submit it adds those options to the selenium script (to be put into www.example.coom/form/info.php) and submits it directly in the browser. Is this possible?

**UPDATE:**
I know this is possible using mechanize, because i have tested it out, but it doesnt so well with javascript which is why i am using selenium.

Comment: This seems like an odd thing to do. Is this for testing or are you trying to create a workflow?

Comment: do you have any idea if this is possible?

Comment: can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

The script has to run first and create the browser session. Currently AFAIK there is no way to take webdriver control of a browser that is already open.

Comment: i am able to run it using mechanize but i prefer selenium so i know its possible with mecahnize. my issue is that mechanize doesnt do well with javascript